# change global variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables, global

Is there a way to define a global variable by user input?
Lets say I use

```
#include...

#define N 12
double array[N][N]; 

void main();...
```

But I would like the user to be able to choose what N is.
Do I have to have N as a local variable or is there a way around this(without macros)?
I've a pretty small program but with a lot of different variables that need the N value.

Alternatively,
 is there a way I could send a group of variables into a function without having to explicitly write them out every time.

for example

```
myfunction(var1,var2,var3...)
```

and instead write something like

```
myfunction(Allvariables)
```

Thanks a lot for Your answers!
This is a great forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int* data;

int main()
{
    int n;
    // get n from the user.

    data = new int[n];

    // use data.

    .
    .

    delete[] data;
}
```

or just forget pointers for ever and use vector!

```
std::vector<int> data;

data.push_back(55);

// just push_back data!
```

=======================================================================

EDIT ::
If you want to use Edouard A. way :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<double>::size_type dataSize = 0;
    std::stringstream convertor(argv[1]);
    {
        if(argc > 1)
        {
            convertor >> dataSize;

            if(convertor.fail() == true)
            {
                // do whatever you want here in case
                // the user didn't input a number.
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<double> data(dataSize);

    // use the vector here.

    return 0;
}
```

I prefere to use lexical_cast in this case, but I am not sure if you have Boost.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef std::vector<double>::size_type vectorSize;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        // err! The user didn't input anything.
    }

    vectorSize dataSize = boost::lexical_cast<vectorSize>(argv[1]);
    std::vector<double> data(dataSize);

    // use the vector here.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I ended up using vectors after all!
And worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

1/ Yes but you need dynamic memory allocation. The program parameters are passed as argc and argv to the main function

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

argc is the number of parameters
argv is the array of null terminated strings representing these arguments

argv[0] is the program itself.

2/You can either use variadic function va_start & the like, or functions overriding, or group your data in a structure and pass that to the function

Comment: Thanks, I will check in the structure alternative , that is probably what I need here!

Answer (score 1):

No, that can't be done this way. You need to use dynamic (runtime) memory allocation (*new[]*). To perform static (compile-time) memory allocation the compiler needs to know the memory block size at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with myFunction but it sounds like you want to look at either creating [a struct](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/structs/struct-time-example.html) or pass a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class (or struct) AllVariables and pass that in.

You don't say whether you want N defined at run time or compile time.  If you want it defined at compile time, you can define N as a compiler command line arguement.